# Breadcrumbs in Wordpress - Can you customise if they display incorrectly?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, breadcrumbs

The breadcrumbs on my site don't display correctly so is someone able to advise how I can create custom breadcrumbs?

If I try and explain, if you visit the link below and select one of the prints:

http://mrsbest.co.uk/mini-best-art-prints/

You'll notice that the breadcrumb, looks like this:

You are here:Home / Christmas / Baby Gifts / Personalised Baby/Child’s Name Print

It displays the Christmas category instead of the actually file path, which should be:

You are here:Home / Mini Best Art Prints / Personalised Baby/Child’s Name Print

I understand why this is occurring - That's because "Mini Best Art Prints" is not a category. It's the title of a page. WordPress doesn't know that I'm displaying those products in that page with a shortcode. There's not any relation between the page and the products.

So I believe the solution is to create custom breadcrumbs. Is there any easy way of doing this, adapting the breadcrumb code or a plugin maybe?

Hope you can help :)

Kind Regards,

Sarah

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's going to be one right answer here - but someone else might drop in with a homer.

**First**

Checkout your theme functions.php, and other files that may have a function related to breadcrumbs. (You ought to be able to search the documents for 'breadcrumbs'.) You may find that the theme is already doing something with the breadcrumbs. That lead may allow you to do your own work in your childtheme.

**Second**

If it turns out that you are running default breadcrumbs (your theme doesn't modify them), see if you can simply get a workaround with your permalink settings and category names. It appears that your URLs are not in agreement with your stated filepath:

If your desired breadcrumb is:

```
Home / Mini Best Art Prints / Personalised Baby/Child’s Name Print
```

It would seem your URL would have to be:

```
mrsbest.co.uk/mini-best-art-prints/personalised-baby/childs-name-print
```

But your real URL is:

```
mrsbest.co.uk/product/personalised-monochrome-bunny-print/
```

**Third**

You can probably start with this and build your custom breadcrumb structure: https://docs.woothemes.com/document/show-product-categories-in-wooframework-breadcrumbs/

Comment: Thanks for your help James!

The theme I'm using is Nantes, so I contacted them in the first instance and it looks like it's Wordpress' default breadcrumbs. Here's their reply:

Comment: "This is correct. This is the way WooCommerce generates the breadcrumbs. It's not something related to the theme.

If you switch to the default theme (Twenty Fifteen) you will see the same structure.

That's because "Mini Best Art Prints" is not a category. It's the title of a page. WordPress doesn't know that you're displaying those products in that page with a shortcode. There's not any relation between the page and the products.

You can create custom breadcrumbs if you want. Please open a ticket in the WooCommerce forum:

https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/woocommerce"

Comment: Great, @SarahB! I hope "Thanks for your help" is the passcode for someone checking the "Correct answer" check mark! ;)